# Is there an easy way to fill the empty space of the page with empty rows in longtable environment?

Tags: page-breaking, longtable

I am typesetting tables in `longtable` environment, each one has different amount of rows (sometimes exceeding one page, sometimes not) and the `\newpage` after each table. I want to add empty rows at the end of each table, so they would fill the empty space after `\newpage` command.

Is it possible to do this somehow?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous: Are you trying to have tabulars inside a large longtable? However, what is the sense of having whitespace after a `\newpage` ?

Comment: I think the question means to fill the page, i.e. have empty lines before the page break, not after it.

Comment: It is always best to compose a [MWE] (http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  This will also help to remove some ambiguity in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `\clearpage` command instead of `\newpage`.  If I understand your question, the `\newpage` isn't properly taking you to the top of a new page as you expect.  `\clearpage` should do the trick.